# reset set timeout - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi there i am trying to send a message when the user starts typing and send a message again when the user stops typing... the problem is after the user stops typing it sends the `stopTyping` message more than once.. i figured out that the problem is with the timer in `keyup` function... it does not reset half way.. i guess...

```
 var typingTimer = '';
    var hahahehehoho = "1";                //timer identifier
    var doneTypingInterval = 10000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example

    //on keyup, start the countdown
    $('#messageText').keyup(function(){
        typingTimer =  setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    });

//on keydown, clear the countdown 
$('#messageText').keydown(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
if(hahahehehoho == "1"){    
    startTyping();
    hahahehehoho = "2";
}
});
```

how do i solve this problem ant help would be appreciated... thanks in advance.. :) ohh and one more thing i used the codes from [Run javascript function when user finishes typing instead of on key up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that is that within:

`typingTimer =  setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);`

you're creating new timeouts, without clearing the old ones. In the end you're only removing the last timeout.

Adding:

`if (typingTimer) window.clearTimeout(typingTimer);` before that should solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

In your `keyup` handler you need to cancel the timeout.

`keyup` is fired at every key stroke so if you type faster enough you're enqueuing more calls to `doneTyping`.