# JavaScript/jQuery: Show DIV until user stops typing in Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, effects

I use a few textboxes on my website (input type=text) and I have that one div, which is hidden (display: none).

Now I'd like the user to enter some text in one of those textboxes and exactly at that moment, the div should appear for a few seconds and hide, WHEN THE USER STOPS ADDING TEXT. The div should also wait until the user stops hovering the div. I really tried hard but couldn't get it done correctly.

Here is a JSFIDDLE-Example to show what I mean:

```js
var InfoBoxHovered = false;

$(".TextBox1").on("input", function() {
    $(".InfoBox").fadeIn();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".InfoBox").fadeOut();
    }, 3000);
 });

$(".TextBox2").on("input", function() {
    $(".InfoBox").fadeIn();
    if (!InfoBoxHovered){
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".InfoBox").fadeOut();
        }, 3000);
    }
 });

$(".InfoBox").mouseenter(function(){
    InfoBoxHovered = true;
})
$(".InfoBox").mouseleave(function(){
    InfoBoxHovered = false;
})

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - //

//The INFOBOX-DIV should APPEAR, when the user enters some text
//The INFOBOX-DIV should DISAPPEAR, 3 SECONDS AFTER THE USER STOPPED ENTERING TEXT
//The Infobox-Div should not disappear after 3 seconds and appear again - it should stay until the user finished entering text and then wait 3 seconds before it fades out
//The InfoBox-div should be visible, as long as the user hovers the div and should then fade out, if the 3 seconds are over
```

```css
.Main{
    background-color: lightgrey; min-width: 100%; min-height: 200px; text-align: center;
}
.Header{
    font-family: Arial; color: red; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;
}
.InfoBox{
    position: fixed; left:0; right:0;background: rgba(0,0,0,.75); z-index: 20; bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto; width: 500px; height: 80px; border-radius: 4px; text-align: center;
    color: white; padding: 15px; font-family: Arial; display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<div class="Main">
    <br/>
    <span class="Header">Input-Fields</span>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="title1" placeholder="Enter Some Text" class="TextBox TextBox1"/>
    <input type="text" name="titlew" placeholder="Enter Some Text" class="TextBox TextBox2"/>
</div>

<div class="InfoBox">
    Information
</div>
```

I tried my very best with different functions like "delay" or "setTimeout" or even check it every few seconds with "SetInterval"... But nothing worked. I tried to explain a few more details in the JavaScript-Field in JSFiddle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to store `setTimeout` in a variable, then *clear* that timeout when needed:

Replaced the `mouseenter` with `hover`, but it will work either way.

**NOTE**
The `.InfoBox` element is initially invisible, so that when it appears under the mouse pointer, it will not get hovered until the mouse pointer gets moved.

```js
// declare timer variable which holds the timeout:
var timer;

$(".TextBox1").on("input", function() {
    $(".InfoBox").fadeIn();
    // clear the timer if it's already set:
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".InfoBox").fadeOut();
    }, 3000);
 });

$(".TextBox2").on("input", function() {
    $(".InfoBox").fadeIn();
    // clear the timer if it's already set:
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".InfoBox").fadeOut();
    }, 3000);
 });

$(".InfoBox").hover(function(){
    // clear the timer on hover, so that the box won't disapear:
    clearTimeout(timer);
}, function(){
    // set the timer again when mouse is outside of the box:
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".InfoBox").fadeOut();
    }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.Main{
    background-color: lightgrey; min-width: 100%; min-height: 200px; text-align: center;
}
.Header{
    font-family: Arial; color: red; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;
}
.InfoBox:hover{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
}
.InfoBox{
    position: fixed; left:0; right:0;background: rgba(0,0,0,.75); z-index: 20; bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto; width: 500px; height: 80px; border-radius: 4px; text-align: center;
    color: white; padding: 15px; font-family: Arial; display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<div class="Main">
    <br/>
    <span class="Header">Input-Fields</span>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="title1" placeholder="Enter Some Text" class="TextBox TextBox1"/>
    <input type="text" name="titlew" placeholder="Enter Some Text" class="TextBox TextBox2"/>
</div>

<div class="InfoBox">
    Information
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of using on mouseenter, use change like so:

```
$(".InfoBox").change(function(){
    InfoBoxHovered = true;
});
```

example jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rec2Ltsm/