# Checking regex expression on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to create my own plugin (without use any external libraries - it's for learning purpose) to validate text typed by user dynamically in regex test function.

In example I have regex pattern:

> ^.{2}$

And javascript function

```
$('#textbox').bind("keypress", function (event) {
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Now, I want to type two dots into textbox, but after first keypress is fired, one dot doesn't match to the pattern and nothing happens because event is prevented.

My question: Is it possible to check if currently typed text matches with regex pattern?

Comment: Assuming you mean that you want to test the current value of the input, not just the last character typed, you can use `$(this).val()` or `this.value` to retrieve it.

Comment: `onkeyup()` event is what you're looking for ? --> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeyup

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes you're right but this still doesn't changing the fact, that first typed dot doesn't matches to regex AFTER it's typed.

Comment: @Baldráni the same as above

Answer (score 5):

Your regex only accept two dots (..), but you're testing a single character!

```
var regex = new RegExp("^.{2}$");

$('#textbox').bind("keypress", function (event) {
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Wanna check current typed text when users finished typing? .. Look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4220182/4718762)

Comment: Yes I test single character but this is my point, how I need to check this fragment of regex after key is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

```
var alpha = /[ A-Za-z]/;
var numeric = /[0-9]/; 
var alphanumeric = /[ A-Za-z0-9]/;

function validateKeypress(validChars) {
    var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(event.which || event.keyCode);
    return validChars.test(keyChar) ? keyChar : false;
}
```

The HTML will have to change to onkeypress="validateKeypress(alpha);"

Comment: It works fine, but returning FALSE still allows the character to be placed in the Input. you should return it like this:  onkeypress="RETURN validateKeypress(alpha);"

Answer (score 0):

You can try keydown as it will trigger as soon as you press a key and before character is displayed in textbox. So if it doesnot match with the pattern you can return out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#textbox').bind("keyup", function (event) {
    var user_input = getElementById ("your_input_id_here");
    if (!regex.test(user_input)) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

So, essentially you should use onkeyup instead and you should check the whole user input, not just the last key

Comment: After first keyup event textbox value will be '.' and it doesn't matches the regex at all just like other answers. Keypress or keydown is irrelevant here.

Comment: So, your user presses ., then the value of the input is cleared, and then you should check whether he pressed . one more time? Then I think you should save the state of '.' being already pressed once somewhere

Answer (score 0):

```
var in_put = document.getElementById("in_put"),
key = null;

in_put.addEventListener("keydown", match_input);

function match_input(e){

    console.log("Key: "+e.key);
    key = e.key;
    console.log("Match: "+key.match(/a/i));//return array of match
    if(key.match(/a/i)){

        //code on succession.
    }else{

        //code on failure.
    }
}
```

> Note: Change /a/i with your /pattern/ig. It only check for input is
>   a/A.