# Dojo events that should trigger after stopping the keyboard typing

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have textbox currently i have attached **DOJO** event and for every key press it is triggering event but is there any event in **DOJO** that should trigger only after keyboard typing is completed.

```
<div  class="cell">
<input type="search" name="searchbox" id="searchbox" placeholder="Search Location" data-dojo-attach-event = "keypress:_getData"/>
</div>

_getData:function(){
         alert("function triggered");    
         }
```

Where this keypress is the event from **dojo/keys**.

> Currently if i type "STACK" the event is triggering 5 times instead it
>   should trigger one time after typing full word or it should trigger
>   only after he stops typing.

Comment: Post your code if you want any help

Comment: @Superdrac i have added the code.

Comment: you can't do it like this. the keypress event work like this, the callback is triggered after each key stroke. Look at this for what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up it's in jQuery but it can give you an idea

Comment: @Superdrac Thanks,I think it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a debounce mechanism.
If you use Dojo 1.10, you can do use `dojo/on/debounce`:

```
on(dom.byId('searchbox'), 'keypress', debounce(this._getData));
```

You can see the unit test for more details:
https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/db66e918cd5a736fa4023741ace82e1bdc0fb612/tests/unit/on/debounce.js