# regex to modify characters in specific case at the end of a word

Tags: javascript, regex

> im working on a translation project and i need to modify some characters at the end for example if user types words like:

typed word: **"yilanin"** => target word (what i want) :**"yilaNG"**

**"suyunin"** => **"suyuNG"**

**"kalinin"** => **"kaliNG"**

**"batinin"** => **"batiNG"**

etc etc...

But i have a problem: i don't want to modify **"nin"** characters if they are at the middle or at the beginning of a word like:

**"kinindan*"" => **"kinindan"**

**"sininteki**"" => **"sininteki"**

**"nin"** => **"nin"**

**"ninkisi"** => **"ninkisi"**

etc etc...

i mean every **"xxxnin"** to **"xxxNG"**,

**"xxxninxxx"** to **"xxxninxxx"**(no modification),

**"nin"** to **"nin"** (no modification)...

i tried to explain my problem very clearly and bascially i hope you understand...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {

  var text2 = $(this).val();
  
  text2 = text2.replace(/([abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprsştuüvyzABCÇDEFGHIİJKLMNOÖPRSTUÜVYZ])nin$/g, '$1NG');
  
  $("#ta_1").val(text2);
  
});
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body>
  
  <textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>

</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yM2qT1/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
(\w)(nin)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yF1hS2/1)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
//setup before functions
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 1000;  //time in ms, 1 second for example
var $input = $('#myInput');

//user is "finished typing," do something
function doneTyping () {
  //do something
}
$("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {

  var text2 = $(this).val();
  var re = /(\w)(nin)([^a-zA-Z])/g; 
var subst = '$1NG$3'; 
  text2 = text2.replace(re, subst);
var re = /(\w)(NG)(\w)/; 
var subst = '$1nin$3'; 
 text2 = text2.replace(re, subst);
  $("#ta_1").val(text2);
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});
$("#ta_1").keydown(function(event) {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
}); 
function doneTyping () {
  var text2 = $("#ta_1").val();
  var re = /(\w)(nin)\b/g; 
var subst = '$1NG'; 
  text2 = text2.replace(re, subst);
  $("#ta_1").val(text2);
}     
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body>
  
  <textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>

</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: @pinug what is output for kinindan?

Comment: it outs "kiNGdan" it shouldn't modify it if its in the middle :/

Comment: @pinug check update,  must type enter or spacebar for replacing word.

Comment: ouups user have to press enter or space then sir,,it is not good for me :/

Comment: This won't work if `nin` is followed with punctuation: `ddddnin.`.

Comment: @pinug check update. I add these code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up So after 1 second `kinin` will replace to `kinNG`. If they continue typing `kinindan`, `kinin` won't be replace.

Comment: @Tim007 oh my god it is very useful for me sir maybe if we reduce to 30 milliseconds it will be better ?

Comment: @pinug `var doneTypingInterval = 1000;  //time in ms, 1 second for example` change this value to any what you want : )

Comment: @Tim007 oh my god thank you so much sir thank you for your interest and thank you for your time sharing, that's what im looking for sir thank you i appreciate :)))

Comment: @Tim007 a bonus question sir how can we modify to its first string i mean after 1 second if user continues typing it returns back to the first string...ex **"kinin"** i wait 1 second and it becomes **"kiNG"** ..but when if user continues to type after 1 second from **"kinin"** to **"kinindan"** how can we change it to **"kinindan"** form

Comment: @pinug check update, i added code to change `kiNG` to `kinin` if continue typing after 1 second.

Comment: @Tim007 sir you are perfect THANK YOU SO MUCH :)

Comment: @Tim007 sir i want to add same case for **"nun"** ,**"in"** i tried several times to add these in plus but it didn't work, it is working only for **"nin"**, how can i add ?

Comment: `var re = /(\w)(nin|nun|in)([^a-zA-Z])/g; ` something like this

Comment: @yes for ex same case for **"kungunun"** but it has to change with **"ng"** => (**"kungung"**),,,or **"anganan"** with **"G"** => (**"angaG"**) ...

Comment: `var re = /(\w)(nan)([^a-zA-Z])/g; 
var subst = '$1G$3'; 
  text2 = text2.replace(re, subst);` edit & repeat these line for other cases.

Comment: @Tim007 i did it sir, but i also changed the variable names maybe i shouldn't :/

Comment: @Tim007 i don't know where am i making mistakes, can you send me a jsfiddle example again to see it sir ?

Comment: @Tim007 sir i got it but it is not working for **"nün"** :/

Answer (score 3):

You need to track two events: `keyup` (to track text input continuation) and `blur` (to check for the string input end). Then, use 2 different replacements:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#ta_1").on("keyup blur", function(event) {
    var text2 = $(this).val();
    if (event.type !== "blur") { // Trigger only on keyup
 text2 = text2.replace(/([a-zA-ZçğıöşüÇİÖÜ])nin\b(?![a-zA-ZçğıöşüÇİÖÜ])([\s\S])/g, '$1NG$2');
    }
    else { // we have blur
   text2 = text2.replace(/([a-zA-ZçğıöşüÇİÖÜ])nin$/, '$1NG');
    }
    $("#ta_1").val(text2);
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>
```

The `keyup` event will check for an already input *word* containing (I guess) Turkish word - `([a-zA-ZçğıöşüÇİÖÜ])nin\b(?![a-zA-ZçğıöşüÇİÖÜ])([\s\S])` - followed with some character that will serve as a word boundary.

The `blur` event will check for a `nin` at the end of the whole string only, and perform the replacement if necessary.

**Update**:

Here is another approach: replace while typing and if another character is typed, revert. However, **this approach won't work if several character combinations can be replaced with one and the same replacement pattern** (it will be unclear what string to restore then):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#ta_1").on("keyup", function(event) {
    var text2 = $(this).val();
    // Replace nin to NG in general
 text2 = text2.replace(/([a-zA-ZçğıöşüÇİÖÜ])nin\b(?![a-zA-ZçğıöşüÇİÖÜ])/g, '$1NG');
   // Restore nin from NG
    text2 = text2.replace(/([a-zA-ZçğıöşüÇİÖÜ])NG(?=[a-zA-ZçğıöşüÇİÖÜ])/g, '$1nin')
    $("#ta_1").val(text2);
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28"></textarea>
```

Comment: thank you so much sir thank you for your interest and your information sir it is very important for me :)

Comment: Not only, there must be at least one more character / focus lose to trigger a replacement. Since the text input is live, you do not have any opportunity to track a "whole word" with `\b` or anything. That is why I suggest using 2 events to check for the input state. With the Unicode letters in place, `\b` is useless :(

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work?

```
text.replace(/([\s\S])nin\b(?![çğıöşüÇİÖÜ])/, '$1NG');
```

`\b` matches a word boundary position such as whitespace, punctuation, or the start/end of the string.

`?![çğıöşüÇİÖÜ]` negative lookahead to specify no match if any of the specified characters are found.

```js
var stringArr = ['suyunin', 'kalinin', 'batinin', 'kinindan', 'sininteki', 'nin', 'ninkisi', 'xxxnin', 'xxxninxxx', 'nin', 'Kalininü'];

var generated = document.getElementById('generated');

for (var i = 0; i < stringArr.length; i++) {
  var newStr = stringArr[i].replace(/([\s\S])nin\b(?![çğıöşüÇİÖÜ])/, '$1NG');

  var li = document.createElement('li');

  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newStr));
  generated.appendChild(li);
}
```

```css
#generated {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  Array List:
  <br>['suyunin', 'kalinin', 'batinin', 'kinindan', 'sininteki', 'nin', 'ninkisi', 'xxxnin', 'xxxninxxx', 'nin'];
  <br>Generated List:
  <br>
  <span id='generated'></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i tried on stackoverflows code snippet tool but not working :/

Comment: I believe you don't need the /g (global) for that :)

Comment: thanks, I have removed the `/g` and updated the formula. Try now.

Comment: @timolawl i tested on stackoverflows code snippet tool but it is not working :/ can you send me a jsfiddle example please ? :/

Comment: i don't know why it is not working on you but I tested timolawl answers on fiddle and it's working fine :)

Comment: @JF-Mechs can you send me a jsfiddle example on this code(the code that i posted) please ?? :/

Comment: Okay! Run the code and compare the alerts to the array.

Comment: @timolawl perfect sir but i don't know how to insert it on my code(the code that i posted) because even i insert your code it is not working sir maybe i had some mistakes,,, :/

Comment: Note that `\b` will find `nin` in `Kalininü` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/kF9cD5/1)). Anyway, the regex `(?!^nin)(nin\b)`  could be written in a cleaner way. Like `([\s\S])(nin\b)`

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful. I was working with the `[\s\S]` but it didn't occur to me just to use it without the lookahead.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
(?!^nin)(nin$)
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/yM2qT1/3)

*JS Code*

```js
var re = /(?!^nin)(nin$)/gm; 
var str = 'suyunin\nabcninshs\nning\ngnin\nning\nkinindan*\nsininteki\nnin\nninkisi';
var subst = 'NG'; 
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
document.writeln(result)
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kmx1uavv/)**

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/nB1l9n)**

Comment: yes it is working but i have a problem to replace it on javascript code,,can you send me a jsfiddle please ?? :/

Comment: addes a `JS` code, `JSFiddle Demo` and `Ideone Demo`

Comment: i mean i don't know how insert in my code maybe i made some mistake not working on my code ://

Comment: `text2 = text2.replace(/(?!^nin)(nin$)/, 'NG');`

Comment: I am afraid I don't know `jquery`..so can't help you to handle `keyup` event

Comment: `keyup` event is causing the problem..can't clarify further because of limited knowledge in jquery