# How to fire click on a button if the user type in an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide, algolia

***Pre-story:*** I am using Algolia search to search on my website.If the user start typing in the input field the results will start appearing on the screen.

**End goal:** close the filters (toggle functionality) by default.

**Issues:** when the user start typing in the input the url change and the filters stay open.

- If I apply the code in the console after the user finishes with typing I can see the button being close.
- If I apply the jQuery codes bellow and while I am typing the filters stay closed, but again once the user stops typing the filters open again.
- Once I finish with typing (input looses focus) the filters open again.

**My approach:**

- First

  ```
  $("input#dropdown_search").on('input',function(e){
      $("b- utton.button.filters__button").click();     
  });
  ```
- Second

  ```
  $('input#dropdown_search').keyup(function() {
      $("button.button.filters__button").click();
  });
  ```
- Third

  ```
  $('input#dropdown_search').on('inputchange', function() { 
      $("button.button.filters__button").click();
  });
  ```
- Fourth

  ```
  $("input#dropdown_search").on('change keyup paste', function () {
      ApplyFilter();
  });

  function ApplyFilter() {
      $("button.button.filters__button").click();
  }
  ```

  It seems that they don't reach the end goal where they keep the filter hidden even after the user stops typing.

Can you please help?

Comment: can you put some of your code?

Comment: `.click();` only triggers other event listeners you've added with `.click`, it won't simulate a native button press for security reasons (you could submit forms without the user knowing).

Comment: @Sergiu Paraschiv the click event works fine as it is targeting the "button.button.filters__button" the problem I face here is that while I type it hides but once I stop it shows again. If I click somewhere else the click function is trigered again

Comment: @Marcel I would like to but it is on my local machine

Comment: You need to show us some relevant code. The one doing the showing and hiding of "filters".

Comment: Are you using [instantsearch.js](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var timer;
$("input#dropdown_search").on('change keyup', function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        ApplyFilter();
    }, 1500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input#dropdown_search").on('change', function () {
    $("button.button.filters__button").trigger("click");
});
```

For your stop typing problem try this answer: [Run javascript function when user finishes typing instead of on key up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `trigger` to trigger `click`

```
$("#dropdown_search").on('change keyup paste',function(event){
 $(".buttonclass").trigger('click'); //trigger .buttonclass button on trigger of events
})
$(".buttonclass").on('click',function(event){
alert("I am clicked")
})
```

[Example jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/nxmfss03/)

Answer (score 0):

> type in first input , that will click the button immediately then fire function to change the second input value

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

 <input type=text id=dropdown_search>
  <input type=text id=dropdown_search2>

  <button id=target onclick="be()">

<script> 
  
     onload = function () {

       var t = document.getElementById('dropdown_search');
       t.oninput = function (){
       
         document.getElementById("target").click();
         
         };
       t.onpropertychange = t.oninput; // for IE8
       t.onchange = t.oninput;

       };

function be() {
var t = document.getElementById('dropdown_search').value;
document.getElementById('dropdown_search2').value=t;}
  </script>
   
  </body></html>
```