# How to define local variables in a jQuery .on function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input HTML element and want to execute a function when there was an input and if this input didn't changed for 3 seconds.

### Code:

```js
$("#search_input").on('input', function() {
  input_value = $("#search_input").val();
  if (input_value != "") {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (input_value == $("#search_input").val()) {
        alert("still the same :) -> go search");
      }
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search_input" placeholder="Search...">
```

The problem is that the handler refresh the `input_value` so it's always the same. How do you set the `input_value` as a local variable, so it's not refreshed?

Comment: Looks like you're just trying to throttle, there are easier ways -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/o11zpub3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the `var` declaration:

```
var input_value = $("#search_input").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

while the var thing is true, it's unlikely the issue.

Looks like you want something like the link below, with the key difference being that you are setting a timeout and clearing the timeout as the input changes. By definition,  the function above is always firing when input is changing so it's redundant.

[Run javascript function when user finishes typing instead of on key up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up)

Answer (score -4):

var var_name = value if it's a normal variable. Like a string or number.
Do $var_name = jQuery_object if it's a jQuery object.

Comment: That's just a naming convention... it's not required by the language and can't be the issue here.

Comment: @JasonP Ik but like you said, its convention

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, at best it belongs in the comment section.

Comment: Yes, and your "answer" does not answer the question or solve the problem.