# jQuery keyup with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like you show an alert message after the function keyup().
For this I use the following code:

```
$('#myInputingNumber').keyup(function() {
  alert ("Key Up")
})
```

This works good and the alert message shows after each keyup call.
But this is not really good.

Is there any way to check, if the user has 2 seconds long no "keyup" and show only then the alert message?

Comment: Possible healping threads- [How to delay the .keyup() handler until the user stops typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/how-to-delay-the-keyup-handler-until-the-user-stops-typing)  And  Search on google->`jQuery keyup with delay`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run javascript function when user finishes typing instead of on key up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delay the .keyup() handler until the user stops typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/how-to-delay-the-keyup-handler-until-the-user-stops-typing)

Comment: Also, check out the concept of "debounce"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
 let delay = (()=>{
      let timer = 0;
      return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
      };
    })();

    window.document.getElementById("myInputingNumber").addEventListener("keyup",function() {
        delay(function(){
          alert('Key Up');
        }, 2000 );
    });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInputingNumber">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one also.

```js
var flag = false;
$(function(){
  $("#demoKeyup")
  .keydown(function(){
    flag = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
      if (flag == true) {
        alert("still key down");
        flag = false;
      }
    },2000);
  })
  .keyup(function(){
    flag = false;
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="demoKeyup">
```