# jquery-Print user's input when user finishes typing instead of on key up?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to print the user's input when he stops typing. My html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jacoco.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js" integrity="sha256-DYZMCC8HTC+QDr5QNaIcfR7VSPtcISykd+6eSmBW5qo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="jacoco.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" id='jacoco' placeholder="Search for a title..">
  </div> 

  <div class="results"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to do what is suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up) post but it doesnt work. My js code is:

```
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 500;  //set wait time until search starts to 5 seconds

//on keyup, start the countdown
$('#jacoco').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#jacoco').val()) {
        alert($("#jacoco").val());
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
});

//user is finished typing
function doneTyping () {
    alert('$("#jacoco").val();');
}
```

So when I am typing in the search box it doesn't print my input.

Comment: Can you please tell what is not working. Whats going wrong?

Comment: See the edits that I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a string `'$("#jacoco").val();'` to `alert()`. `'` should be removed. And also use `console.log` instead of `alert()`

```js
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 500;  //set wait time until search starts to 5 seconds


//on keyup, start the countdown
$('#jacoco').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#jacoco').val()) {
        //alert($("#jacoco").val());
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
});

//user is finished typing
function doneTyping () {
   console.log($("#jacoco").val());

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>IMDB Search</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jacoco.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js" integrity="sha256-DYZMCC8HTC+QDr5QNaIcfR7VSPtcISykd+6eSmBW5qo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="jacoco.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" id='jacoco' placeholder="Search for a title..">
  </div> 

  <div class="results"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I also needed to enclose the code inside a  ```$(document).ready()``` .