# How to do "submit form after user stop typing" in vuejs2

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2, laravel-6

I have a search module in which: *when a user stop typing it should search the name*.

What I think the solution is to do a `timeout` when a user `keyup`. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up)

```
<input type="text" @keyup="textSearch($event)">

textSearch(e){
    var timer;
    clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        alert('searching...');
    }, 2500);
}
```

The code were all working, **the problem is** why when I type 3 character in just 1 second it pops out 3 alerts? I expect there should be one pop-out since it waits for 2.5 seconds.

Is there something wrong with the code? Need help Sirs

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-debounce

Comment: @Hamelraj thanks, in that case no need to `setTimeout`

Comment: yes just simply you can use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is a solution:**

`setTimeout` is fine -- alternatively, you can use `debounce` [Vue-debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-debounce)

```
<input v-debounce:400ms="myFn" type="text" />

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    myFn(val) {
      console.log(val) // => The value of the input
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 15):

If I understand you problem correctly the timeout you clear each time you run `textsearch()`is not the one you last created, but the one you just declared with `var timer`.
I'd suggest storing your timer variable in your data properties instead to have clearTimeout clear the right timeout.

Something like this:

```
data: {
    timer: undefined
},
methods: {
    textSearch(e){
      clearTimeout(this.timer)

      this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
          alert('searching...')
      }, 2500)
    }
}
```

Working fiddle of your code with my modifications:

https://jsfiddle.net/MapletoneMartin/yjxfsehz/2/

Good luck!

Comment: solution is working. But I prefer the marked answer thank your for the response Sir. Voted up!

Answer (score 2):

What I do to fix this issue is that I take `timer` variable in Vue data because when `textSearch` method called inside timer function is reassigned.

```
data () {
    return {
        timer: null
    }
}


textSearch(e){
    clearTimeout(this.timer);

    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        alert('searching...');
    }, 2500);
}
```

I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: solution is working. But I prefer the marked answer thank your for the response Sir. Voted up!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for this is, to use a `watch` instead of using `event-keyup`. You must create `model` first.

```
<input type="text" v-model="searchTxt">

data(){
    return{
        searchTxt: ''
    }
},

watch: {
    searchTxt: function(val) {
        if (!this.awaitingSearch) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert('searching');
            alert(this.searchTxt); //alert value

            this.awaitingSearch = false;
          }, 2500); // 2.5 sec delay
        }
        this.awaitingSearch = true;
    }
}
```

[More information](https://techformist.com/wait-for-user-to-stop-typing-in-search-fields-on-vue-ui/)

Comment: solution is working. But I prefer the marked answer thank your for the response Sir. Voted up!