# Javascript search delay and collect input from eventlistener

Tags: javascript, settimeout, delay, debouncing

I have a simple input box. When I write something, I want it to be delayed. The problem I have is after the delay when writing characters very fast it calls the console.log multiple times.

### What happened now

I type `a` and wait. Then I type `b c d` fast and wait. Then `e f` fast and wait. It catches up which I don't want. I want it to collect what I type, but not output it until the delay is done.

```
a
.
.
.
b c d
b c d
b c d
.
.
.
e f
e f
```

### What I want to happen

```
a
.
.
.
b c d
.
.
.
e f
```

```js
var searchtimer;

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector("#search").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    searchtimer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(e.target.value);
      clearTimeout(searchtimer);
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text">
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4220126/1267304) out.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Yes, OPs code starts a new timeout for every `input` event, but OP doesn't need _"another timer to get the input end"_.

Comment: Clear the timeout _before_ you create a new one and it should work as expected (clearing the timeout when the timeout already happended doesn't make that much sense...)

Comment: @Andreas yeah you're right, its the same thing.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, that was it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expected behavior looks like `debounce`.

It seems to me that you should `clearTimeout` before creating the new one.

```js
var searchtimer;
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector("#search").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    clearTimeout(searchtimer); // <--- The solution is here
    searchtimer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(e.target.value);
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text">
```

---

### More detailed explanation:

- It is basically a way for *eliminating unwanted signals from an input*. So if the defined duration hasn't passed, the previous action should be eliminated by `clearTimeout(searchtimer);`
- **Keynote:** The operator keeps track of the most recent value.

Read post ["throttleTime vs debounceTime in RxJS"](https://namitamalik.github.io/throttleTime-vs-debounceTime-in-RxJS/) to understand in detail.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution with step by step explanation**

So you need to [debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function).

The below code shows how a function is executed only when the time difference between 2 keystrokes is at least 2 seconds.

```js
let count=0;

//If we call this directly from the HTML, the function will be 
// fired for every click, which hinders the performance
let myFunction =()=>{
  document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = "Hello World "+ ++count ;
}

//So we'll call this debouncing wrapper function from the HTML instead
let myFunc=letsDebounce(myFunction,2000);

//The wrapper calls setTimeout to execute its argument fn after
// the specified delay, but if the triggering event fires again
// before the setTimeout duration finishes, then the timer gets reset
// so the previous call is ignored
function letsDebounce(fn,d){
  let timer;
  return function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer=setTimeout(fn,d);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunc()">Debounce</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: myjscoffee, I edited the comments to be (hopefully) more clear, and added a reference link. The only change I made to the code itself is in the line `timer=setTimeout(fn,d);`. If you don't think these changes are an improvement, feel free to revert to your original version.

Comment: @Cat Sure , thanks for making it more readable and improving the post