# Change Iframe src based on user input

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe

I can't seem to find anything that works, but I need some html that makes an iframe based on what url entered into a text box. I use iframes to unblock websites on my school chromebook but its a hassle if I want to just check a website and see how it works on an iframe by making a whole new website. I just wanted something to easily preview a URL in an iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the iframe source, you'd need a listener for when the input changes and when it does, change the source of the iframe by updating the [`src`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_src.asp) property. Setting up the listener, you could do something like this:

```js
// Grab the element by ID
document.getElementById("example_input")
  // Add the event listener to "input" 
  .addEventListener("input", exampleFunc);
  
function exampleFunc(event){
  // Grab iframe by ID
  let iframe = document.getElementById("example");
  // Update the source
  
  // First grab the input that was typed into
  let input = event.target;
  // Next get the value of that input
  let newUrl = input.value;
  
  // Now update the "src" property of the iframe
  iframe.src = newUrl;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <input type="url" value="https://example.com" id="example_input">
  <iframe id="example" src="https://example.com" width="1000" height="450" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Although in this case, you may not want to update it every input but rather when a user stops typing, which has a solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up) question.

Please also note that many websites will not allow for iframes to make connections for various reasons (X-Frame-Options header, Content Security Policies, etc.), with examples of sites that won't work being Google and YouTube.