# Run javascript function when user stop typing instead of on key up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

i'm working on eccomerce site and in cart.php
i want to make the qty update automatically after 5 second from stop writing
this is the java script code

```
<script>
function updateQty(productId) {
    var qty = document.getElementById('qty-' + productId).value;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('qty-' + productId).setAttribute('data-quantity', this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.open('POST', 'cart.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send('obd=' + productId + '&opd=' + qty);
}

// Retrieve the quantity when needed
var quantity = document.getElementById('qty-' + productId).getAttribute('data-quantity');

</script>
```

i want to make it updating after 5 second of inactive or stop writing

i saw a way to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up)

but when i try it, it didn't work

```
// Define a timer variable to keep track of the timeout
var timer;

function updateQty(productId) {
  // Clear any existing timeout when the function is called
  clearTimeout(timer);
  
  // Get the current value of the input field
  var qty = document.getElementById('qty-' + productId).value;
  
  // Send the AJAX request to the server
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var updatedQty = this.responseText;
      document.getElementById('qty-' + productId).value = updatedQty;
      document.getElementById('update-success-msg').style.display = 'block';
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('update-success-msg').style.display = 'none';
      }, 3000);
    }
  };
  xhr.open('POST', 'cart.php', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.send('obd=' + productId + '&opd=' + qty);
  
  // Set a new timeout to update the quantity after 5 seconds
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    var newQty = document.getElementById('qty-' + productId).getAttribute('data-quantity');
    if (qty != newQty) {
      updateQty(productId);
    }
  }, 5000);
}

// Retrieve the quantity when needed
var quantity = document.getElementById('qty-' + productId).getAttribute('data-quantity');
```

Comment: The timer has to be in the code that processes the `keyup` event, not the code that sends the AJAX. Like in the question you linked to.