# change jQuery don't work

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, events

I have this code:

```
        $(".input_photo").click(function() {

            $.post("ajax/imagefile.html", function(img){
                complete: $(".bp_load").fadeIn(0).html(img);
            });
        });
```

`Imagefile` is a simple HTML page that contains the form and input type file with ID `imageform`.

And I have another code:

```
            $('#photoimg').live('change', function(){
                $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                    target: '.preview'
                }).submit();
            });
```

I searched in the web, and I understand that `live` is deprecated, and I have changed to `on`, but it doesn't work. The input type file is changed, but the event doesn't triggered.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Do you get any console errors?

Comment: What jQuery version do you use? $.on() added in 1.7.

Comment: As I known, This event is seem to be limited to <input> elements.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443292/how-to-implement-onchange-of-input-type-text-with-jquery

Comment: @user2465422 live() has been removed from 1.9.x, so use delegation with .on()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equivalent to live using `.on()` is:  {delegate syntax}

```
$(document).on('change', '#photoimg',function(){
                $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                    target: '.preview'
                }).submit();
            });
```

Comment: FANTASTIC roasted, TANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!