# Jquery on Input not working on dynamically inserted value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, alert

I'm trying to alert a value using jquery when it is generated from a javascript code, the value is generated on the input box the problem is jquery cannot detect the changes, commands i tested are "change, input" but when i manually input a value jquery triggers

sample code:

value is dynamically generated on the javascript and pushed / inserted to the inputbox, the value is not manually generated
**javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("displayDID").value = DisplayName ;
```

**html:**

```
<input type="text" id="displayDID" />
```

**jquery:**

```
$('#displayDID').on("input" ,function() {
            var work = $(this).val();
            alert(work);
        });
```

the value of the id="displayDID" changes but jquery cannot detect it after execution.

sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SU7bU/1/

Comment: it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/paRPL/1/

Comment: What about to change "input" to 'keyup' if you want to alert every changes, or to 'change' if you want to alert the changes after focusout

Comment: it works fine on manual input, but doesnt when the value is pushed from javascript

Comment: Try this one: $('#displayDID').val('some value').change(); - this should fire you onchange event.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/LGAWY/141/ more information on this link, see Davids answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443292/how-to-implement-onchange-of-input-type-text-with-jquery

Answer (score 3):

add trigger to it

```
$('#gen').on('click',function() {
    $('#field').val('val').trigger("change");
});


$(document).on("change",'#field' ,function() {
    var work = $(this).val();
    alert(work);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ytexj/

Comment: please read the description, it is no manually triggered, it is triggered by the system.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have added the script before input is ready.Due to which, event is not getting set on that element.write the code on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#displayDID').on("input" ,function() {
        var work = $(this).val();
        alert(work);
    });
})
```

or use event delegation:

```
$(document).on("input",'#displayDID' ,function() {
        var work = $(this).val();
        alert(work);
    });
```

Comment: still not triggering the jquery

Comment: can you create the fiddle??

Answer (score 0):

Ok I will propose you one answer and let's see if it solve your problem.
If you use keyup, and you insert 3350 value, you will display 4 alert, and I think you want to display only 1 alert.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var interval;
 $("#variazioneAnticipo").on("input", function() {
  var variazioneAnticipo = $("#variazioneAnticipo").val();
  clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setTimeout(function(){ showValue(variazioneAnticipo) }, 1000);
 });
});

function showValue(value) {
   alert("ANTICIPO VARIATO: " + value);
}
```

```html
<input id="variazioneAnticipo" class="rightAlligned form-control" style="width: 60%" type="number" step="0.01" min="0" value="3" />
```

I explain it, when you input anything into the input, will trigger a setTimeout in 1 sec, if you press another key under this time, we clear the timeOut and we triiger again, so you will only have 1 alert 1 sec after the last input insert.

I hope it helps you, and soyy for my english :D