# Auto Calculate MySQL data price based on 1 input field

Tags: php, mysql

How can I change all prices 1 time instead of one by one?
I want to just type a number in a field, and each price will be calculated based on my formula and updated.

So I have a database, in there, there are some prices.
I already have a php page, where I can edit the prices one by one.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0fWl.png]

So the name and price values are loading from my database.
This is the PHP file:

```
<?php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","***","***") or die("Error Connect to Database");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("***");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM orders";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
?>
<table width="562" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th width="201"> <div align="center">Name</div></th>
    <th width="213"> <div align="center">Price</div></th>
    <th width="126"> <div align="center">Edit </div></th>
  </tr>
<?php
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $objResult["gehalte"];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $objResult["prijs"];?></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="prijsedit.php?id=<?php echo $objResult["id"];?>">Edit</a></td>
  </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
<p>Total price:
  <label for="textfield">:</label>
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield"> 
  <a href="#">Update</a>
</p>


<?php
mysql_close($objConnect);
?>
```

If I press edit, it will go to a another php page where I can change the price value and save it:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMgUh.png]

But I just want to type 1 price in an input field, and that value will be auto calculated by * or - and show that as results.
So if I type a total price, let say: 2000 then I want each price automatically to change and then I can press Update.

So that I can give each name a formula like: 2000-500 = SHOW THIS VALUE
And that I only put some numbers in the total field, all the prices will be calculated automatically and I don't have to change all prices one by one.

Like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM40T.png
[image]

The Edit PHP page:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form action="save.php?id=<?php echo $_GET["id"];?>" name="frmEdit" method="post">
<?php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","*","*") or die("Error Connect to Database");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("*");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id = '".$_GET["id"]."' ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery);
if(!$objResult)
{
    echo "Not found CustomerID=".$_GET["id"];
}
else
{
?>
<table width="540" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th width="161"> <div align="center">CustomerID </div></th>
    <th width="203"> <div align="center">Name</div></th>
    <th width="154"> <div align="center">Price</div></th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="text" name="txtCustomerID" size="5" value="<?php echo $objResult["id"];?>"></div></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtName" size="20" value="<?php echo $objResult["gehalte"];?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtEmail" size="20" value="<?php echo $objResult["prijs"];?>"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  <?php
  }
  mysql_close($objConnect);
  ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And Save PHP :

```
$strSQL = "UPDATE orders SET ";
$strSQL .="id = '".$_POST["txtCustomerID"]."' ";
$strSQL .=",gehalte = '".$_POST["txtName"]."' ";
$strSQL .=",prijs = '".$_POST["txtEmail"]."' ";

$strSQL .="WHERE id = '".$_GET["id"]."' ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
if($objQuery)
{
    echo "Save Done.";
    header('Location: edit.php');
}
else
{
    echo "Error Save [".$strSQL."]";
}
mysql_close($objConnect);
?>
```

Comment: It have to be just Like this:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/yM40T.png

Comment: Just need to used javascript

Comment: That looks like a table.

Comment: @jewelhuq Thanks, i was already thinking that.. Where can i find a demo or example like how i want it? I searched 3 days but no results :(

Comment: Check out :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443292/how-to-implement-onchange-of-input-type-text-with-jquery or try onchane textbox value change in google

Comment: Thanks but still i have a another problem if i edit one price, i just see 1 name and price not everything!

Comment: Can you show the code you use to handle the single item edit?

Comment: @MarkLeiber Yess offcourse, i just edited the post! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks, but it's save.php that I'm looking for.

Comment: @MarkLeiber I'm Sorry i just added it, i need something simple, i don't have to seee al the prices -> If i have just 1 input with  a button where i can type EG: 3000 and press Update , that all the prices will changed in the database based on the math for each ID .

Comment: Where `2000/10 = 200, 2000*2=4000, 2000-500 = 1500` come from?

Comment: @RubahMalam So if i type 2000 in this field: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yM40T.png Then i want that that value so: 2000 will be calculated for each Database ID.. So that i can set it like: For ID=2 math is: 2000*2 = 4000<-- And save the results in the Database

Comment: @d3xt3r, how complicated do the formulas need to be?  Is it sufficient if they are just "enteredValue operator x" (examples: 2000 * 2, 2000 - 500, 2000 / 2) or will the math be more sophisticated than that?

Answer (score 1):

> This is the right answer

1. Create a new .php file, and put this in there:

   ```
   $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","***","***") or die("Error Connect to Database");
   $objDB = mysql_select_db("***");
   $strSQL = "SELECT id FROM orders";
   $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");

   $value = isset ($_POST['inputField']) ? $_POST['inputField'] : '';

   if (!empty($value)) {
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)) {
           $price = calculate_price ($row['id'], $value);
           $strSQL = "UPDATE orders SET prijs =". $price. " WHERE id = ".$row['id']. "";
           $result = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
       }

       echo "<script>alert('Update Successful!');</script>";
   }
   ```

   function calculate_price ($id, $value) {
       $price = 0;
       switch ($id) {
           // Calculation here for id 0
           case 0: 
               $price = $value / 10;
               break;
           // Calculation here for id 1
           case 1: 
               $price = $value / 10;
               break;
           // Calculation here for id 2
           case 2: 
               $price = $value * 2;
               break;
           // Calculation here for id 3
           case 3: 
               $price = $value + 4;
               break;
           default :
               break;
       }
       return $price;
   }

   $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#button').click(function(){
               var value = $('#inputField').val();

   ```
           if (value === '') {
               alert("Please input a value");  
               return false;
           }
       })
   })
   ```

***** Stackoverflow does a little weird if i paste the whole code in code tags**

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I would recommend using multiple SQL Statements.

```
<?php
//declare update value to variable x 
//SQL Statement 1: select first value from database with ID2
//do math for first value using x and set it to new variable y
//SQL Statement 2: Update database with new value y for ID1
//Do the above for each value
?>
```

I hope this answers your question. Let me know, if you need a further explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single `UPDATE`.

Here are the assumptions I'm making about the formulas:

- they can be tokenized by spaces
- they have three tokens, e.g. X(space)operator(space)Y
- they always have the operator as the middle token

Here is the set up that I'm using to mimic your data (obviously you don't need to run this part):

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  id numeric,
  gehalte varchar(20),
  formula varchar(20),
  prijs numeric
);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1, '8karaat', 'n / 10', 80);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (2, '14karaat', 'n - 500', 150);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (3, '18 karaat', 'n * 2', 200);
```

Here is a `SELECT` statement to show you what the `UPDATE` will be doing:

```
SELECT id
, gehalte
, formula
, prijs AS prijs_original
, SUBSTRING_INDEX(formula, ' ', 1) AS part1
, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(formula, ' ', 2),' ',-1) AS part2
, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(formula,' ',-1),' ',1) AS part3
, CASE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(formula, ' ', 2),' ',-1) 
  WHEN '+' THEN
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(formula,'n',2000), ' ', 1) + SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(formula,'n',2000),' ',-1),' ',1)
  WHEN '-' THEN
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(formula,'n',2000), ' ', 1) - SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(formula,'n',2000),' ',-1),' ',1)
  WHEN '/' THEN
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(formula,'n',2000), ' ', 1) / SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(formula,'n',2000),' ',-1),' ',1)
  WHEN '*' THEN
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(formula,'n',2000), ' ', 1) * SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(formula,'n',2000),' ',-1),' ',1)
  END AS prijs_calculated
FROM orders;
```

Results:

```
id  gehalte     formula  prijs  part1   part2   part3   prijs_calculated
1   8karaat     n / 10   80     n       /       10      200
2   14karaat    n - 500  150    n       -       500     1500
3   18 karaat   n * 2    200    n       *       2       4000
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8816c/1

The columns part1, part2, and part3 illustrate how the formula is tokenized.  For example, if the formula is "n / 10", the first token is 'n', the second token is '/' and the third token is '10'.
In the `CASE` statement, the second token (the operator) is evaluated, and based on that the math is executed as: part1 (operator) part3.
You could add the modulo operator if you want as another case, but I figured it was unlikely to be used in your formulas.

So the `UPDATE` statement would look like this:

```
UPDATE orders 
SET prijs = CASE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(formula, ' ', 2),' ',-1) 
      WHEN '+' THEN
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(formula,'n',2000), ' ', 1) + SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(formula,'n',2000),' ',-1),' ',1)
      WHEN '-' THEN
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(formula,'n',2000), ' ', 1) - SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(formula,'n',2000),' ',-1),' ',1)
      WHEN '/' THEN
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(formula,'n',2000), ' ', 1) / SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(formula,'n',2000),' ',-1),' ',1)
      WHEN '*' THEN
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(formula,'n',2000), ' ', 1) * SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(formula,'n',2000),' ',-1),' ',1)
      END;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a962/1

Note that I don't have a `WHERE` clause as I'm assuming that you are displaying and updating all records.  If this isn't the case you'll need to provide the appropriate `WHERE` clause to limit the records that are updated.

One more important note.  **You should really be using prepared statements and parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection.**  In the above `UPDATE` statement, 2000 is the value from your form post.  Instead of using `$_POST["theFormField"]`, you should use a parameter.  There is a great answer demonstrating how to do it here:
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)