# How to find change in value of elements in with particular class

Tags: jquery

I have an edit screen, there is a  section inside in which i have lots of elements like select,input etc. Now i need to find out whether the user has changed any values which was already existing using Jquery.
I have to find whether there was a change in value while submitting the form.
Consider a div like this,

```
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group required">
<label class="control-label">Port</label> 
    <select name="portId" id="portId">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Chennai</option>
        <option value="2">Kochi</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label">Operator Name</label> 
    <input type="text" id="operatorName" name="operatorName">
</div>
<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label">Attachment</label> 
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
</div>
```

Comment: need [mcve]  of HTML and the jQuery you've used.

Comment: you may track text changes using on.input event like this `$('<selector>').on('input',function(e){...}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting Data changes in Forms using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807159/detecting-data-changes-in-forms-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

These events are used to check if an element has been modified or dirty. For implementing this in jQuery specifically **[.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** is the event which can be bound to an element.

For Dirty checking in forms, [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.dirty) is the NPM plugin.

Comment: i have drop down which by default had 1st option selected, i'm changing it to option 2 and again i changed it back to option 1, in this case the value is not changed while submitting but change event will consider this as a change right?

Answer (score 1):

Please share your code snippet which will help others to clearly undestand your question and give you the right answer. Anyway depends on your situation you need fire on change event on all elements like select, input and store old value in data attribute ex data-id='1' and compare with the data value and changed value.

```
$( "input" ).on( "change", function() {

   if($(this).text() != $(this).data('id'))
   {
        alert('you have changed');
   }
});
```

Comment: how to store old value in data attribute

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do. As I said please share your code snippet or something to understand your situation. Normally on page load, you can assign values to the data attributes.

Comment: when page load assign default values to data attribute